# Hide the text in an `<input type="text">` without hiding the insertion point

Tags: html, css

I'm writing an advanced filter tool, and I'd like to have live syntax highlighting for the query field, which is a standard `<input type="text">`. I am doing this by listening for changes, parsing the query, and displaying a highlighted version at the same visual location as the text. I would like to display the highlighted text *behind* the `<input>` for simplicity. Then, all I need to do is make the text in the `<input>` invisible. However, the obvious ways of doing this (color: transparent or opacity: 0) also hide the insertion point. I tried fiddling around with `text-stroke` and `text-shadow`, but to no avail. How can I hide the actual text without moving it or hiding the insertion point?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with was positioning the styled text visually above the unstyled text, then setting a `text-stroke` on the unstyled text to shrink it just a bit.